# Physicist: Need help understanding a line in a derivation

Tags: mathematical-physics, poisson-distribution

The derivation I'm looking at is the Poisson distribution in M. Fox's "Quantum Optics" Chapter 5.

> Now by Stirling's Formula:
>
> $\lim_{N \to \infty} [\ln N!] = N \ln N - N $
>
> we can see that
>
> $\displaystyle\lim_{N \to \infty} \big[\ln \big(\frac{N!}{N^n(N-n)!}\big)\big] = 0$

It's not clear to me why this limit equates to zero. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Hi @user1844282, Welcome  to MSE. Take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to the site and read some questions/answers on the site. These things will help you in understanding the site in a better way.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed in this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\log{\left (\frac{N!}{N^n (N-n)!} \right )} &= \log{N!} - n \log{N} - \log{(N-n)!} \\ &\approx N \log{N}-N - n \log{N} - (N-n) \log{(N-n)} + (N-n) \text {[By Stirling's Formula]}\\ &= (N-n) \log{N} - (N-n) \log{(N-n)} - n \\ &= (N-n) \log{\left (\frac{N}{N-n} \right )} - n \\ &= -(N-n) \log{\left (1-\frac{n}{N} \right )} - n \\ &\approx -N \left ( -\frac{n}{N}\right ) - n\end{align}$$

Thus the limit is indeed $0$ as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: I think you mean $N\rightarrow\infty$ in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{N! \over N^{n}\pars{N - n}!} &
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{\root{2\pi}N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N} \over
N^{n}\bracks{\root{2\pi}\pars{N - n}^{N - n + 1/2}
\expo{-\pars{N - n}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
{N^{N + 1/2}\expo{-N} \over
N^{n}\bracks{N^{N - n + 1/2}\pars{1 - n/N}^{N - n + 1/2}\expo{-\pars{N - n}}}}
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{\expo{-n} \over \pars{1 - n/N}^{N}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ N\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,\bbx{\large 1}
\end{align}